# Как написать эффект тумана или дыма для заднего фона картинки или блока?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, canvas, glsl

Очень интересно реализация тумана (или дыма) для заднего фона какого нибудь блока.

Пример:

```css
.main_parent_container {
    width:300px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 50px #e62429;
    border: 2px solid #e62429;
}
.main_parent_container > img {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_parent_container">
   <img src="https://i.redd.it/wiulfk7q42a21.jpg" alt="something" />
</div>
```

Для этого блока я на задний фон дал два свойства `box-shadow: 0 20px 50px #e62429; border: 2px solid #e62429;` вместо них я бы хотел на задний фон добавить  дым либо туман.

Примеры я  нашел такие [**пример тумана**](https://codepen.io/hiroshi_m/pen/YoKYVv)  из Гарри Поттера,  [**второй пример**](https://codepen.io/deawx/pen/EBQYvr), [**и третий**](https://codepen.io/thomasvaeth/pen/EevQPV) самый простой на  SCSS

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос, любой из приведенных Вами эффектов по-своему не плох...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вопрос в том что у меня не получилось применить эти эффекты для заднего фона как это сделать ?

Comment: нормально никак, а так - как в способа с огненным кольцом, одна канва под другой

Comment: можно конечно и backgroung image каждый кадр обновлять, но боюсь это будет плохая затея.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Восстановил но очень сомневаюсь что у кого то получится если  не получилось у вас.

Comment: зря Вы так, просто я остановился на варианте с наложением, меня устраивает...

Comment: еще я в принципе знаю способ как 2 разных webgl приложения заставить использовать одну канву, чем собственно можно подобное сделать для канвы. но Вам же для обычного блока надо.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да для самого обычного заднего фона картинки :)

Comment: в принципе очень простенько наверное можно и на голос css, попробую попозже

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да конечно можно и что нибудь на CSS главное сам эффект а не технология реализации

Comment: Создать и стилизовать дочерние блоки либо стилизация before after

Comment: @ИгорьМакарчук пример с кодом в студию!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно двигать несколько бэкграундов с полу-прозрачностью, вот что получается:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  animation: bg 13s infinite linear;
  background-image: 
    url(https://data.whicdn.com/images/138510361/large.png),
    url(https://data.whicdn.com/images/138510361/large.png);
  height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background-position: -100% 70%, 100% 30%;
    background-size: 200%, 200%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 70%, -100% 30%;
    background-size: 200%, 200%;
  }
}

.main_parent_container {
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 50px #e62429;
    border: 2px solid #e62429;
    transform: translate(calc(50vw - 50%),calc(50vh - 50%));
}
.main_parent_container > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_parent_container">
   <img src="https://i.redd.it/wiulfk7q42a21.jpg" alt="something" />
</div>
```

Comment: Выглядит отлично.

Comment: А без изображения реализация сложна?

Comment: @doox911 по ссылкам в вопросе есть пример где во фрагментеом шейдере формирунтся картинка, в целом там немало математики

Comment: @StrangerintheQ фото облаков не рабочий надо обновить )